# Django pagination problem - pages not getting paginated

Tags: html, django, django-filter

I'm using Django-filters to filter results. The filter is working correctly, but now the pagination is not working. It's being rendered, but now all the products are being displayed in one page. I was using `paginate_by = 6` as it is a *class based view*. Even after filtering results, for example there are 8 products matching the filter, everything is being displayed in one single page. Why is it not working? Can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance!

My filters.py:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Item

class ItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Item

        fields = {
            'category': ['exact'],
            'price': ['lte']
        }
```

My views.py:

```
from .filters import ItemFilter

class homeview(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'products/home.html'
    paginate_by = 6


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = ItemFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

My index.html:

```
<div class="card mb-4">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="container">
      <form method="GET">
        {{ filter.form|crispy }}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Filter</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>List Of Items</h1>
  <div class="row mb-4">
    {% for item in filter.qs %}
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ item.image_url }}">
          <div class="box-element product">
            <h6><strong>{{ item.title }}</strong></h6>
            <h6 class="text-success">Category - {{ item.get_category_display }}</h6>
            <hr>
          </div>
      </div> 
    {% endfor %}
  </div>


<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
          {% if is_paginated %}

            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
              {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                <a class="btn btn-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
              {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
            {% endif %}

          {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

Comment: You may need to add `ItemFilter`s definition to your question.

Comment: yes I have added it , *Edit*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all You're not using page object created by django's ListView methods. Technically you pass a new queryset instead. Therefore you're listing all the results instead of paginated results.

super().context already has a page object which is not used here. since you use ItemFilter

Here's how I'd handle the situation. without django_filters though

forms.py

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.CharField()
    price = forms.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
from .forms.py import FilterForm
class HomeView(ListView):

    model = Item
    template_name = 'products/home.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_filter_args(self):
        request = self.request
        filter_args = {}
        filter_args['category'] = request.GET.get('category')
        filter_args['price__lte'] = request.GET.get('price')

        # To remove filter arg if the value is null. to avoid errors
        filter_args = {key: value for key, value in filter_args.items() if value}

        return filter_args

    def get_queryset(self):
        filter_args = self.get_filter_args()
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(**filter_args)

        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = FilterForm()
        return context
```

In order to prevent the applied filters from losing on pagination, use a helper to build url for pagination add this file in a templatetags folder inside the app folder (same path where views.py, models.py etc...)

temptag.py

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag    
def paginate_url(field_name, value, urlencode=None):
    get_query = f'{field_name}={value}'
    if urlencode:
        qs = urlencode.split('&')
        _filtered = filter(lambda p: p.split('=')[0] != field_name, qs)
        querystring = '&'.join(_filtered)
        get_query = f'{get_query}&{querystring}'
    return get_query
```

you can import the template helper inside html file
html file

```
{% load temptag %}
<div class="card mb-4">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="container">
      <form method="GET">
        {{ form|crispy }}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Filter</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>List Of Items</h1>
  <div class="row mb-4">
    {% for item in object_list %}
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ item.image_url }}">
          <div class="box-element product">
            <h6><strong>{{ item.title }}</strong></h6>
            <h6 class="text-success">Category - {{ item.get_category_display }}</h6>
            <hr>
          </div>
      </div> 
    {% endfor %}
  </div>


<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
          {% if is_paginated %}

            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?{% paginate_url 'page' 1 request.GET.urlencode %}">First</a>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?{% paginate_url 'page' page_obj.previous_page_number request.GET.urlencode %}">Previous</a>
            {% endif %}

        {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if page_obj.number == num %}
            <a class="btn btn-dark mb-4" href="?{% paginate_url 'page' num request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ num }}</a>
          {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?{% paginate_url 'page' num request.GET.urlencode %}"</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
          <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?{% paginate_url 'page' page_obj.next_page_number request.GET.urlencode %}">Next</a>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?{% paginate_url 'page' page_obj.paginator.num_pages request.GET.urlencode %}">Last</a>
        {% endif %}

      {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Now after filtering results, whenever I'm going to another page, the filter breaks.

Comment: I don't understand. can you elaborate ? are you using any of these components in another page ?

Comment: I mean, for example, there are 12 products matching the filters, so there will be two pages of result. When I'm clicking to go on to the second page, the filter breaks, and the usual second page is shown without any filters.

Comment: The reason is the get query ?page=2 replaces the previous filter queries I'll update the code with a workaround.

Comment: I've updated the code to preserve the get queries. Let me know if it works fine now. :)

Comment: Now no items are being displayed on my home page. Only the form is being displayed.

Comment: Bro now one problem is that, when I'm going to my second  or third  or any page, the filter is not breaking, but it is redirecting me to the first page, and it's happening all the time, with and without filters

Comment: I've done an edit: temptag  def paginate_url(field_name, value, urlencode=None):  sorry with this, blind coding is bit hard xD

Answer (score 0):

Write your get_context_data() like that

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter'] = ItemFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=items)
    return context
```

Comment: You didn't put the pagination inside of your html
Check this link : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/pagination/

Comment: Yes I added pagination in my index.html, but still, it's not working

*index.html pagination part* included above

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using django-filter. However, my solution was using [List.js](https://listjs.com/), as I had a table that I not only want paginated, but I wanted the table headers to be sortable.

You can probably use List.js here, even though you don't have a list or table of data (you can also check out [some example codepens](https://codepen.io/javve) by the creator of List.js).

index.html:

```
<h1>List Of Items</h1>
  <div id="paginate-items"> <!-- Need a container with a unique ID for List.js -->
    <div class="row mb-4 list"> <!-- Must include the class "list" for the div containing the data to be paginated -->
      {% for item in filter.qs %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ item.image_url }}">
            <div class="box-element product">
              <h6><strong>{{ item.title }}</strong></h6>
              <h6 class="text-success">Category - {{ item.get_category_display }}</h6>
              <hr>
            </div>
        </div> 
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination"></ul>
  </div>
  ...
  <!-- You'll need to include jQuery and List.js just before the close of the '<body>' tag: -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
```

Then, in a separate .js file:

```
var myData= new List('paginate-items', {
  page: 3, // refers to how many items per page
  pagination: true
});
```

And some simple styling in a separate .css file:

```
.pagination li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}
```